# Proxy issue after update Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy, android-studio-4.1, android-studio-3.4

Previously I used Android Studio 3.4.0.0 with proxy config to my company proxy URL and set systemProp properties in gradle.properties. Everything works as normal.

Last week I update Android Studio to 4.1.0.0. It asked me whether keep the original settings or delete and I choose to keep the original settings. After that, I face the issue that the connection always refused. I tried re-install both new and old versions and it's not working anymore.

Any solutions or suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you check "HTTP PROXY" setting in android studio?

Comment: @MiladBahmanabadi Yes, I set it as same as I used previously.

Comment: May you post your proxy setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

1. Completely uninstall Android Studio from PC
2. Re-install Android Studio
3. Set proxy config as I used previously
4. Restart Cntlm

It's work!!

Thank you for every suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

- Try `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`
- Check your `gradle.properties` for `https` configs

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=[IP ADDRESS]
systemProp.http.proxyPort=[PORT]
systemProp.http.proxyUser=[USERNAME]
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=[PASSWORD]
systemProp.https.proxyHost=[IP ADDRESS]
systemProp.https.proxyPort=[PORT]
systemProp.https.proxyUser=[USERNAME]
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=[PASSWORD]
```

- Check `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` for gradle cache

Hope this will help.